# SVN file based access

Tags: svn, visualsvn

**Running:**
**VisualSVN Server v2.1.3**
**SVN v1.6.12**

I'd like to be able to express the following *"Only the users in the 'CanModifyConfig' group can modify config files for an entire directory and it's subdirectories"*

At the minute that involves me creating the group and going to each and every *.config file and ensuring that only this group has **rw** access on it. We have many *.config files and this is extremely tedious. How can I achieve this in a more time efficient manner?

Comment: Probably best done with hooks. They are there to extend the functionality, and that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Another way of doing it could be with a script that changes many config files in one go, and save you the time and effort.

Comment: I have a [hook script](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that may help you with this particular task. This script allows you to use pattern matching for who can modify what files.